# Can a project adopt AngularJS as its template engine while being a non-MVC project?

Tags: angularjs, javascript-framework

I use [Pure](http://beebole.com/pure/) as the template engine for my current project. It is, however, rather minimal in terms of what it offers. I am in need for a template engine that allows "conditional statements". AngularJS is a candidate that I am interested in. I have been reading a lot about the MVC framework lately and it seems quite interesting. If I have the resources to spare later on, I would definitely want to try to apply AngularJS on my project. For now, I just want to use AngularJS's template engine without converting my project to MVC. Is this viable? If so, please suggest any good resources for me to learn its template language. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to clean up the [tag:pure] tag - [see meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171779/what-is-the-pure-tag-for) for more info. I don't know anything about [tag:haskall], so can I ask for your advice on other tags to use on this question? Would something like `beebole-pure` or `purejs` or `pure-templating-language` work for this question?

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen - personally, I prefer `purejs` but pure.js is used in many different contexts, so I would suggest `purejs-templating`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose to only use the template bit in angular, yes. Check the angular website for tutorials. It's quite straight forward.

Comment: Although it's true that one can use only the template bit from AngularJS, I would like to point out to newcomers that AngularJS is a more integrated solution for web development problems, so the benefit of using only its template doesn't really outweigh the overhead of setting/using AngularJS. If a JS template engine is all you need, you would perhaps be better off with Handlebars/Mustache.